# Print data array value in DataTables(Server Side) column, inside string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I'm using Datatables plugin in one school project. But I can not make it work server side version. In the client side version I have some crud botons to manage the data. But I can not achieve to put that buttons in the sever side version. I try to use it with mRender wich aloud me create HTML objects. But I want to put some data array value inside this string. But I can't make it. Can someone help me with this one please.

This es what I try.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mita').DataTable({
            "columns": [
                {"data": "llave"},
                {"mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                return '<a href="'+print_r(data.llave)+'">Download</a>';}},// Problem Here !!!
                {"data": "llave"},
                {"data": "titulo"},
                {"data": "titulo"},
                {"data": "fecha_inicio"},
                {"data": "fecha_fin"},
                {"data": "fecha_fin"},
                {"data": "fecha_fin"},
                {"data": "fecha_fin"}
            ],
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
            "ajax": {
                url: 'demo2.php',
                type: 'POST'
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you still trying to achieve this with datatables or are you trying to write this algorithm yourself? If you want to use datatables and it's not working, please include the error above. Also quick sanity check, did you include the datatables library?

Comment: Do you want the print link to be in the same column as `llave` or in an adjacent column?

Comment: Yes datatables ir working fine. What i want to do is print an array value inside a string. It dont give me errors, but is not displaying the table. If i take off +print_r(data.llave)+ the table displaing right. But what i whant t do is put a value inside

Comment: llave is the id of my record. I want to put this value inside an href to do something with taht specific record.

Comment: Have you tried using a breakpoint on the `function` to see what the contents of `data.llave` actually are at the time that `mRender` is called?

Comment: Also, you say that you don't get any errors, but the table doesn't display. If the table isn't displaying, you almost *certainly* have some Javascript error. Double-check your console, if the whole table stops displaying when you have that `+print_r(data.llave)+` part, I'd be extremely surprised to see *no* Javascript errors.

Comment: Not tried that yet. I mean, in the code you can see that i print llave value in the first column. It prints right. But i want to put that llave value inside href on the second column, thats why im using **mRender**

Comment: Yes i know its an error print it like that. But that is the general problem here. Tha cant print that llave value inside href :/

Comment: Yes, but you're not actually just printing `llave` in the first column, you're telling DataTables where to look for the data. In the second column, you're dynamically generating a link based on the value of `data.llave`. The reason I make this distinction is that by documentation, `data` is the data for that column, not all the data. Seriously, try to step through and see the exact contents of `data.llave` at that point in the function. Also, check your console for Javascript errors and if you find one (you should) post it in the question.

Comment: I get it, i'll try that and see what happen.

Answer (score 0):

This fix maybe help you , try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mita').DataTable({
        "columns": [
            {"data": "llave",
              "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                return '<a href="'+data+'">Download</a>';
              }
            },
            {"data": "llave"},
            {"data": "titulo"},
            {"data": "titulo"},
            {"data": "fecha_inicio"},
            {"data": "fecha_fin"},
            {"data": "fecha_fin"},
            {"data": "fecha_fin"},
            {"data": "fecha_fin"}
        ],
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "ajax": {
            url: 'demo2.php',
            type: 'POST'
        }
    });
});
```